# how to unregister BaseAdapter that depends on other source

Tags: java, android, observer-pattern, baseadapter

I have a `MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter` that extract information from **JniSource**. `MyAdapter implements JniSource.Observer` and get a callback when underlying **JNI** data is changed.

My Question: I can `JniSource.registerObserver(MyAdapter)` in constructor but where to call `JniSource.unregisterObserver(MyAdapter)`.

`MyAdapter.finalize()` cannot be the place because **JniSource** is still having reference (inside `LinkedList`) to `MyAdapter`.
If I don't call `JniSource.unregisterObserver()` this would cause a leak.

Extra Note: all **JniSource** methods are static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is simple, when MyAdapter have observer, then MyAdapter register itself to the JniSource. using this way i do not have to mantain anything absolute. (life cycle is relative).

Added benifit: This also prevent from unwanted changed callback from JniSource since there are no observer for MyAdapter

```
public abstract class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements JniSource.Observer {
    private int observer_count = 0;

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        super.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
        if(observer_count == 0) {
            JniSource.registerObserver(this);
        }

        observer_count++;
    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        super.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);
        //FIXME: what if unregisterDataSetObserver got called for a non-registered observer?
        observer_count--;
        if(observer_count == 0) {
            JniSource.unregisterObserver(this);
        }
    }

    public void onJniSourceDataChanged() {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Dispose Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispose_pattern) in this case.

*(From Wikipedia)*

> The dispose pattern is a design pattern which is used to handle resource cleanup and prevent resource leaks in runtime environments that use automatic garbage collection.

---

1. Create an interface `Disposable`

   ```
   public interface Disposable {

       public void dispose();
   }
   ```
2. Implement it in `MyAdapter` class and call the `JniSource.unregisterObserver(MyAdapter)` method in the implemented `dispose` method.
3. Call `dispose` method when you are done using `MyAdapter` object. This has to be done manually as garbage collector does not guaranty if an object would be destroyed.

---

**Edit:**
In case of android, life-cycle methods are best positions for your code. In this case, `onDestroy` method seems to be the best candidate. In other platforms, programmer has to manage life-cycle somehow (mostly manually). This should be thought about at that time.

Comment: then, how will dispose() be called?   it is ListView that will decide when it is done with MyAdapter.

Comment: but than again same question: how will ListView decide when it is done?